# Have react-debugger in the addon debug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox-sidebar

I am currently developing a web extension for Firefox and Chrome. I am writing it in ReactJS/Redux. So I am used to these plugins:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/react-devtools
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reduxdevtools

However when you try to debug your `sidebar_action` or your `browser_action`, React/Redux debugger won't be loaded as they are also web extensions. Is there a way to make them available in this "add-on debugger".

Comment: Have you tried using the native Version instead of the extension? https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/master/packages/react-devtools/README.md#usage-with-react-dom

Comment: I didn't know this thing but Firefox says `The extension "React Developer Tools" is not allowed to access moz-extension://3d8fd18f-945e-3b45-a94f-cdb541b51b25/popup/index.html?uilocation=tab`

Comment: Does somebody know?